# Is std::map insert thread safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, thread-safety

I know that the `std::map` class is thread unsafe in read and write in two threads. But is it OK to insert in multiple threads?

```
void writeMap()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        long long random_variable = (std::rand()) % 1000;
        std::cout << "Thread ID -> " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " with looping index " << i << std::endl;
        k1map.insert(std::make_pair(i, new p(i)));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::srand((int)std::time(0)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        long long random_variable = (std::rand()) % 1000;
        std::thread t(writeMap);
        std::cout << "Thread created " << t.get_id() << std::endl;
        t.detach();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Like such code is running normal no matter how many times I try.

Comment: In general, no.  From a pure multi-threading perspective, no object can protect itself from unsequenced/concurrent access by two threads, and that logic extends to meaning that non-static member of an object that may modify the object cannot protect the object when used directly by multiple threads.   This is why the calling code (in your case, the code that calls `std::map::insert()`) must take care of synchoronisation (using mutexes, etc) - the called function cannot provide absolute guarantees unless it is protected that way.

Comment: The general rule is that writes cannot occur concurrently with any other read or write.  So two writes cannot be concurrent, and need to be synchronised.  `std::map::insert` is a write operation, since it (potentially) modifies the map.

Comment: Theoretically so, but why is the actual code running without any problems, please explain

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, there are no defined constraints on what happens.  One perfectly possible outcome is that what happens appears, in your testing, as "running without problems".   An equally possible outcome is that it passes your testing, but then malfunctions when used by a customer.

Comment: It is working by luck. It may be a combination of the coding of the std library implementation and/or the CPU architecture and/or some concurrency problems do not surface when two threads are running on the same core but if, suddenly, they get scheduled onto separate cores then the bugs can surface and/or etc....

Answer (score 0):

No, `std::map::insert` is **not** thread-safe.

Most standard library types are thread safe only if you are using separate object instances in separate threads. Take a look at the thread safety part of container's [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: `const` functions don't modify the object.   That doesn't mean they can be considered "thread safe" if another thread modifies the object.   If calling `std::map::size()` and `std::map::insert()` concurrently on the same map but different threads then they need to be synchronised.

Comment: @Peter theoretically, only `std::map::insert` needs to be synchronized but, if you really want to be sure, there would be no harm to protect `std::map::size` too

Comment: Not true, NutCracker.    `std::map::size()` accesses state of the object.  `std::map::insert()` modifies state of the object.   If they are called by different threads, on the same object, the calling threads need to ensure the calls are synchronised.

Comment: -1 for the last paragraph. `std::map::size` does not provide any thread-safety. @Peter is right. It's like you have an `int` and you modify it with one thread while constantly displaying it in the other. **Both** have to be synchronized, not only the one that writes to the `int`. A `const` method, even if it doesn't change any `mutable` fields, is not by definition thread-safe.

Comment: @Fureeish why does the standard then says: _All const member functions can be called concurrently by different threads on the same container._ Refer to the link I have provided in the answer.

Comment: @NutCracker 1) cppreference is **not** the standard. 2) I cannot seem to find anything like that in the [standard papers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.dataraces), but feel free to point me out at the correct part. 3) I belive what you linked assumes that there are no threads that use non-`const` methods. If you *only* use `const` methods then yes, it's thread-safe. If you don't, it's not.

Comment: @Fureeish ok, I understand. I will correct my answer. I knew that protecting all the member methods is necessary but this cppreference link somehow confused me

Answer (score 0):

program is complex，to some extent，like magic（LOL）.
The code run results are different on various IDE.
Before, I used VS2013, it's always right. 
But on vs19 and linux,the result of the same code is wrong.
Maybe on vs2013,the implement of MAP  has special way.

Answer (score 0):

As @NutCracker has mentioned, `std::map::insert` is not thread-safe.

But, if the posted code works fine, I think the reason is that the map fills very fast by one thread and as a result, other threads are not modifying the map anymore.